# How do you convert a raster of digital values of ndvi to an index of NDVI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, ndvi

I have a raster of the Mean May Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) that is a composited measure of VGT daily images, acquired between 2000 and 2009 in May, using the Mean Compositing algorithm (Vancutsem et al., 2007) in order to generate an average composite. The processed VGT-S10 products is in digital numbers (from the vegetation sensor). However, in my model I transformed these values from the digital number to an NDVI index ranging from 0 to 1, the original range of NDVI, using the following equation: NDVI = (0.004∗Digital Number)−0.1.  I would now like to convert the raster so I can use the predict function to model species ditribution models which include this predictor. How would I best do this?

I am using ArcGis 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to calculate a raster you use the function "Map Algebra" from the spatial analyst extension. There you can put into your calculations. You put into the expressions field your calculations like :

`outras=0.004*  >double-click your raster here from the top-left<  -0.1`

The "outras" is needed to save the output into the file you specified in the lower part. Without it it is not calculated.